# Visual Studio 2012 error .NET 4.6

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6

Once I open a .NET 4.6 project I got this message

> Configuring Web http://localhost:64886/ for ASP.NET 4.6 failed. You must manually configure this site for ASP.NET 4.5 in order for the site to run correctly. ASP.NET 4.6 has not been registered on the Web server. You need to manually configure your Web server for ASP.NET 4.6 in order for your site to run correctly.

And I'm sure that .NET 4.6 is installed on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it isn't .Net framework problem. It's Visual studio problem.

You can install that [visual studio 2012 update](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/0/2/A02C37E0-77F7-448A-BD5C-F66AB1F78DBC/VS11-KB3002339.exe) and it will work smoothly.

The details of the update can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44907